# How would inheritance be used in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, inheritance, design-patterns

So I'm reading a book on database design principles and came on the chapter about inheritance, but I'm confused on how I could "connect" sub classes with their super class in MySQL ?

The table structure would, for example, look like this [image]

So how would I relate these two sub classes with their super class so that I could easily do a query similar to " hey, get me a correct contract type for a Person he is assigned to ".

A person could have one of each, or even both of them, if, for example, a Person is a student doing a part time job as a lecturer as well to finance it's schoolarship, or a Lecturer on some kind of extra course ( so he is a student as well as a lecturer ).

Comment: Contract may have person_id, contract_type_id wich relates to student and lecturer contract.

Comment: Wouldn't that restrict that a Person can have only either Student_Contract or Lecturer_Contract and not both at the same time ?

Comment: No, it would not, since a person can have multiple contracts. It would only restrict the contract itself because a contract has to be of either student or lecturer type.

Comment: @NovicaVukobratovic Do I answer your question? If not, what can I add?

Answer (score 5):

There are various approaches to solve this problem; OR-Mappers like Hibernate implement them all. But you can do this manually, too:

1. The most simple one is called "Single Table Inheritance". This includes using a discriminator column which allows you to store the type name or another type identifier in order to be able to seperate types. This is the easiest way to work with, but be aware, there are these tradeoffs:

   - you cannot use NOT NULL constraints in columns only present in one of the leaf types
   - broad tables with many columns become even broader with new types, this will decrease the overall performance
2. The second one is called "Join Inheritance" and it reflects your UML model. You will have a table "Contract", a table "student_contract" and a table "lecturer_contract", every table only keeps the data related to the type, not of it's supertype. You will use a SQL JOIN to select the data of one specific type. 
   This approach enables you to have small tables (fast) but growing complexity with more inheritance (more JOINs). The core tradedoff is :

   - good distribution on data
   - horrible sql on really complex inheritance structure (which are bad style anyway!)
3. The last approach is "Table per Entity" and this means you will create a table for each leaf type - in your case "Student_Contract" and "Lecturer_Contract". This is a nice approach, but beware, there also is a tradeoff ;-) You have to generate you key values safe along all tables (e.g. by using a SEQUENCE). This construct is not supported by every database (e.g. mysql does not support SEQUENCES as a construct reusable along multiple tables).

For academic purposes, I'd suggest you to try 1) for the sake of simplicity

For real projects, choose wisely - most projects I made based on 2)

EDIT:

You example would end up- depending on the relationship between Person and Contract -  in something like this:

```
PERSON (1) ----- (N) PERSON_CONTRACT (N) ---- (1) CONTRACT
```

(M to N relationship, if the person can be multiply assigned to a contract)

or

```
PERSON (1) --------- (N) CONTRACT
```

(1:N relationship between person an contract. A contract can only have one person, a person can have multiple contracts)

Comment: This is too much information for a simple solution.

Comment: I disagree, this platform is not intended to solve other ppls homework. Merely the authors are asked to show up a way how to find a solution. And, there are in fact three approaches to solve inheritance in a database. Your solution is short but matches only 1/3rd of the possible solution (in fact, it is number 1) in my text).

Answer (score 2):

### First Solution:

- Have different dominant ID's names

  - The solution is to name each db `table` with a different `id name`.

#### Example:

- person_id → person
- contract_type_id → contract
- student_contract_id → student_contract
- lecturer_contract_id → lecturer_contract

---

### Second Solution:

- Use [SQL Joins](http://www.sql-join.com/)

  - > An instruction to a database to combine data from more than one table.

Comment: just my 2 cents: you can have seperated ID prefixes, but this is not mandatory. You can model Person (#ID, name, phone) (1) -- (*) Contract (#ID, ...). The relation will only contain the foreign keys Student_Contract (#(PERSON_ID, CONTRACT_ID)). The selection normally includes JOINs on the tables. Finally, your approach is an ER-approach and not an OO-approach. Since the input was an object model there will be a discrepancy between the object model and the table representation in the db.

Answer (score 0):

For the implementation of supertype and subtype, one must first extract ALL of the common attributes into the supertype. Next, create a lookup table that contains a reference to EVERY subtype that is included in the superclass.  Each subtype is a one-to-one relationship with the supertype sharing the same Id as a primary key.
This cannot be implemented in a RDBMS without some serious trigger nonsense.
Therefore, it's wise to implement this in application code, in the business layer, inside a child, extended from an abstract table class, that represents any table. Don't forget to implement transactions for entries into this use case.

Answer (score -1):

contract into a board 3 new fields are needed: `person_id`, `contract_type` and `contract_type_id`

```
person_id INT foreign_key
contract_type ENUM('student', 'lecturer')
contract_type_id INT foreign_key
```